# How to set label to auto height in smartface?

Tags: smartface.io

I am having label in my Smartface project for description field. 
Is there any way to set the height of the label to auto or setting height basing on the text length.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property for that.

Check the attached picture below :

[image]

If you make the label's autosize property true, then it's width property changes automatically in order to show the text.
If this is not enough for your text, you can also use multiline property. This makes your label's height property change.

If you don't want to change label's size, then you can use "Adjust font size to fit". If  you set an appropriate value for min font size, then your text font gets smaller in order to fit into the label.

Comment: Thanks for the reply merve. But, this didn't work for me. As per the Smartface documentation @http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/label/ 
"AutoSize : Changes the size of the label to fit the content . It changes only the width value if the label is single line."
I dont want to fix the height of the label since i am having some other control below the label. If description is less, then there will much space in between.

Comment: You can try to use multiline plus autosize. Have you tried like that?

Comment: Yeah. i tried it but, issue still exist. Any things else i can try?

Comment: You have a label, and you don't know about its text length, right? And you want to see all the text inside this label, if text is long, you want to see a bigger label, and if text is short, you want to see a smaller label. If this is also right, then there might be another problem. Can you please tell which device you are using? And also, you are using the latest Smartface 4.4.0 right?

Comment: Yes merve. you are right. I need to auto set my label height depends on text length.
I am using motorola g2:andriod device.
currently i am using Smartface 4.3. I didn't upgraded to 4.4.0.

Comment: Can you try with another device? Or can you try with new setup. But don't forget to backup your project. Because if you don't, you cannot open it again with Smartface 430 after once you opened it with Smartface 440.

Comment: I tried with some other devices too. Will try with 4.4.0 then. Whats included in 4.4.0? Any licensing issues will occur in developing?

Comment: For Android there is no limit, no licence is needed for emulator or publish. But with 440 you won't be able to use iOS Emulator. As I said, don't forget to backup your project. I will also try with Lg but not available right now.

Comment: Upgraded to 4.4.0. Now its fine. Thanks merve.